# Are there web frameworks for Boost::asio?

Tags: c++, boost

It sounds a bit strange using C++ for web developing, but with node.js becoming popular I think it's reasonable for C++ to do web stuff.

node.js is similar to Boost::asio, they are both asynchronous and having high performance. I think it is natural for C++ have its own web framework based on Boost::asio.

So are there web frameworks for Boost::asio, like Express, Geddy? And why if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [pion](http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-network-library), which is a boost::asio based HTTP server written in C++. You could use that as a starting point for a C++ web framework.

Answer (score 1):

They exist, but all the ones I know of are "in-house". Once you're writing C++ using asio, it's not that big a leap to take something like google ctemplates, write a webserver and do a framework.

Answer (score 1):

the boost beast  is avaliable now
https://github.com/boostorg/beast

Comment: Beast is a truly awesome library authored by Vinnie Falco using Boost Asio.